# ENOTFOUND proxy.server.com when running `heroku create`

Tags: heroku, proxy

The Heroku documentation says that I should use the following proxy settings when I use the `heroku create` command:

> ```
> > set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> > set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
> > heroku login
> ```

Unfortunately, I am receiving the following error message:

> ```
> !    ECONNRESET: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.server.com
> !    proxy.server.com:8080
> ```

How can I fix this error?

I am also having trouble cloning the GitHub repo which is mentioned in the Heroku documentation, so I have to download it manually.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time on Stack Overflow. Your second question about cloning a repository from GitHub should be asked separately. Please make sure to include details about exactly which repository you are trying to clone, and link to the relevant page in the Heroku documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That documentation is under the heading [Using an HTTP proxy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy). Are you sure that you need to use an HTTP proxy? In many cases you won't need one; simply running `heroku create` will work.

If you are sure that you need an HTTP proxy you should make sure to replace `proxy.server.com` with your actual proxy server's name or IP address. `proxy.server.com` is just an example.